# Is there any good alternative for Keras library?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am currently using keras as a deep learning library on top of tensorflow. I just want to know is there any other library which is more efficient/easier than keras.

Comment: I believe Keras's interface is most intuitive among all of the library (my personal opinion). You may want to look at pytorch if it meets your nees.

Comment: When you say efficient / easier, it would be better if you could elaborate on what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @apsdehal Thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely take a look at pytorch.

Comment: @NischalHp I just want to know the alternative. It would be great if you could suggest me any library for implementing neural networks(specifically deep feedforward nets) other than keras.

Comment: There are good uses of Lasagne (it works on top of Theano)

Comment: Could you give an example of what you find inefficient or hard to do in Keras? Otherwise, without some objective criteria on what you need, it cannot really be answered in a Stack Exchange format . . .

Comment: @DavidDale Thank you for your suggestion. I would also check Lasagne.

Comment: Yes, ezcodesample.com
It has multiple matching examples, same data processed by Keras and ezcodesample.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say which is more efficient or easier but [MXNet](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/) exists, has interfaces to most languages (python, scala, R, C++, perl, Julia), and the code looks fairly similar to keras.

https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/

Another one that I've come across is [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/), mostly because people seem to share a lot of pre-trained nets in their [model zoo](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/model_zoo.html).

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/

Update: I didn't see [caffe 2](https://caffe2.ai/) but I think this is quite separate to the original caffe.

Finally I've not fully had time to check out H2O's offering in [deep water](https://www.h2o.ai/deep-water/) which is an alternative to Keras but still sits on top of TF/MXNet/Caffe

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend pytorch. You can find good tutorials [here](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/).

Answer (score 1):

Keras is a high-level API that can be used on top of [`TensorFlow`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), [`CNTK`](https://github.com/Microsoft/cntk) and [`Theano`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano). You can use each of the low-level APIs but the problem of those is that you can get complicated if you design very deep nets whilst dealing with `Keras` is much easier. Consequently, [`Keras`](https://keras.io/) is designed for accelerating deep nets' designing. `Keras` is opensource like the underlying libraries it comes for and I guess its project is not for `Google`. `TensorFlow` itself has a high-level API, namely [`TFLearn`](http://tflearn.org/). I cannot say which is [better](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/25318/28175) but the point is that try to master one of them perfectly.

It seems that `plaidML` Keras backend is also available which enables training on **AMD** graphics.

Comment: Nowadays there is also the plaidML keras backend which allows training with amd cards.